# iOS push notification - send a message to everyone

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm writing my first iOS app with push notification and so far so good. I'm able to send notifications from a web server as long as I enter the device token of the receiver.

So I was wondering: Is there a simple way to send a notification to everyone who has the app installed? Or do I have to make the manually register with the push server when it launches?

Is there any guidelines on how this is done?

Comment: Any updates in the last 6 years? Since google (Firebase) have topic push notification, so you don't need to store all the Android devices anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to enter any devices manually on the server and shall not. It is the application which has the responsibility to register its token on your server.

The server must keep a list of all tokens of all the registered devices. Whenever you want to push a message to all the devices, loop through your list of device tokens.

If the user does not want to receive any push notifications, the user can cancel push notifications in the settings.

Please read the official documentation about [Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html).

Comment: Any updates in the last 6 years? Since google (Firebase) have topic push notification, so you don't need to store all the Android devices anymore...

Comment: If you have Firebase, the tokens still are stored in the Firebase cloud. You can find them in the Firebase console. However you don't have to create your own database to store them. One way or the other, the tokens needs to be saved in the backend.

Comment: so firebase just store the tokens for me... i get it. Thanks Johan.

Comment: i cannot find them in my firebase console. Any hint where they are?

Answer (score 0):

You have to save all the Data on your server. Then you can loop through all your data and voila you can send a message to everyone.

And yes you have to register all manually to the push server.

Comment: The user has the ability to cancel push notification either at installation time or later in the preferences. It is the application that is responsible for registering the token. Please see the official Apple documentation about push notifications.